# Transformer.transform Error: Unable to open 'WfdCommon.jar'

Tags: java, android, xml

It's my first intention to create XML file for android using TransformerFactory and I have these errors:

> W/﹕ Unable to open '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': No such file or directory
>   W/art﹕ Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/WfdCommon.jar': I/O Error

I'm using this class:

```
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class CreateXMLFile {
    public static void save(String fName) {
        try {
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory =
                DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder dBuilder =
                dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document document = dBuilder.newDocument();

            // adding root element to document
            Element rootElement = document.createElement("rootelement");
            document.appendChild(rootElement);

            // write the content into xml file
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory =
                TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer =
                transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
            File file = new File(fName);
            // Output to file
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(file);
            transformer.transform(source, result);
            // Output to console for testing:
//            StreamResult consoleResult = new StreamResult(System.out);
//            transformer.transform(source, consoleResult);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I call *.save* method like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .......

    CreateXMLFile.save("test.xml");

}
 ....
}
```

Testing to consol works well, but when I'm trying to write the content to a file, it throws Exeption.
I was trying to get information about *WfdCommon.jar*, but could not find any. I have no idea where to dig. Can anyone help me, please?